# Iterate through list while parsing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to download worksheets for this workout, all the workouts are split on different days. All that needs to be done is add a new number at the end of the link. Here is my code.

```html
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
theurl = "http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/workout-routines/gain-10-pounds-muscle-4-weeks-1?day="
urls = []
count = 1
while count <29:
   urls.append(theurl + str(count))
   count +=1
print(urls)
for url in urls:
    thepage = urllib
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    init_data = open('/Users/paribaker/Desktop/scrapping/workout/4weekdata.txt', 'a')
    workout = []

    for data_all in soup.findAll('div',{'class':"b-workout-program-day-exercises"}):
        try:
            for item in data_all.findAll('div',{'class':"b-workout-part--item"}):
                for desc in item.findAll('div', {'class':"b-workout-part--description"}):
                    workout.append(desc.find('h4',{'class':"b-workout-part--exercise-count"}).text.strip("\n") +",\t")
                    workout.append(desc.find('strong',{'class':"b-workout-part--promo-title"}).text +",\t")
                    workout.append(desc.find('span',{'class':"b-workout-part--equipment"}).text +",\t")
                for instr in item.findAll('div', {'class':"b-workout-part--instructions"}):
                    workout.append(instr.find('div',{'class':"b-workout-part--instructions--item workouts-sets"}).text.strip("\n") +",\t")
                    workout.append(instr.find('div',{'class':"b-workout-part--instructions--item workouts-reps"}).text.strip("\n") +",\t")
                    workout.append(instr.find('div',{'class':"b-workout-part--instructions--item workouts-rest"}).text.strip("\n"))
                    workout.append("\n*3")
        except  AttributeError:
            pass

init_data.write("".join(map(lambda x:str(x), workout)))
init_data.close
```

The problem is that the server times out, I'm assuming its not iterating through the list properly or adding characters I do not need and crashing the server parser. 
I have also tried to write another script that grabs all the link and put them in a text document, then reopen the text in this script and iterate through the text, but that also gave me the same error. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo here:

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
```

You probably wanted:

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Otherwise you are trying to open an array of urls rather than a single one.

Comment: So I'm purposefully using URLs - urls is a new list I created using theurl + count on line 7.

Comment: Oh! Yes I see, let me try it.

Comment: Perfect that worked wonderfully thanks for the extra set of eyes!